# Get-запрос к защищенному rest api

Tags: python, api, rest, get, powershell

Задача сосотоит в том, что у меня есть необходимость отправить get запрос на REST API. Сложность состоит в том, что на первом этапе проводится проверка SSL сертификата на сервере, допустим https://134.44.100.60. Со стороны сервера имеется собственный СА от которого я и получил сертификат. Также, у меня настроен VPN туннель с данным сервером. С валидацией сертификата проблем не стало, т.е. я отправляю запрос на сервер и получаю вменяемый ответ. После этого мне необходимо направить запрос к REST API (например, /api/v1/Accountant/service?toDate=2020-10-08) на получение информации, но я получаю ответ, что данных URL-ов на сервере не существует. Что является довольно странным поведением, поскольку к данным URL ежедневно подключаются другие пользователи и успешно ими пользуются. Операционная система с которой работаю Windows server 2012R2

Что я использовал для отправки запроса:

1. PowerShell 5.1. Invoke-WebRequest и Invoke-RestMethod (пробовал оба, но различие увидел только в представлении возвращаемых ответов, но могу ошибаться). Пример:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://134.44.100.60 -Certificate $cert -SessionVariable 'ses'
```

Здесь все хорошо и я получаю 200 ответ от сервера и никаких ошибок, предупреждений и прочего

Далее пробую обратиться к REST API:

```
$rest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://134.44.100.60/api/v1/Accountant/service?toDate=2020-10-08 -H $headers -WebSession $ses
```

И, вот, тут я и получаю `URL not found`. `headers` содержит базовую аутентификацию

2. Python requests. Здесь долго мудрил с сертификатами, но так и не получил нормального результата. Т.е. я конвертировал в .pem файл и пробовал вот так

```
import requests

url = 'https://134.44.100.60/api/v1/Accountant/service?toDate=2020-10-08'
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, verify=(cert.pem))
```

ошибка выглядит примерно так `[SSL] PEM lib [._4303]`

Так, вот в чем вопрос: куда дальше? Документация по API говорит, что ссылки вот такие и точка. Пробовал, конечно, с ними поиграться, но это как слепой котенок тыкаешься и не понимаешь, что делаешь. Точно знаю, что у API ip адрес отличается от адреса хоста, примерно такой: 134.44.101.100, но ping на него не проходит

Comment: «у API ip адрес отличается» — ну вот вам и ответ, почему вы получаете ошибку.

Comment: пока вы про python забудьте на время. Тут надо понять кто вам дает такое сообщение сам nginx или ПО на которое nginx делает проброс запроса. Может же и само ПО вам отдает 404  так ка по /api/v1/Accountant/service?toDate=2020-10-08  у него нет данных и оно так запрограмировано. Да и комментарий выше тоже верный, посмотрите туда ли вы обращаетесь

Comment: там Apache. Что у API другой ip я узнал случайно, как бы информация не по мою душу была. Я думаю попробовать сегодня другие форматы дат. Я где то совсем близко к решению, не понятно где =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение такое, если кто будет также копаться как и я. Сначала перепроверил сертификаты от CA. С помощью openssl верифицировал и собрал цепочки. Следом, начал работать под Linux с curl, что немного более гибко, чем Windows Server 2012.

1. Обратился к серверу

```
curl --verbose https://134.44.100.60
```

2. Посмотрел, где может затыкаться запрос и нашел вот такие строчки

```
 subjectAltName does not match 134.44.100.60
 SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '134.44.100.60'
```

это могло означать, что серверный сертификат не содержит ip-адрес как имя хоста

3. Смотрим какие имена распологаются в поле subjectAltname

```
openssl s_client -connect 134.44.100.60:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -text | grep -A1 "Subject Alternative Name"
```

4. Вывод был достаточно большим и содержал примерно 20 имен
5. Заглянул в документацию к API и нашел необходимое имя для моего запроса (accounting.local)
6. И воспользовался `curl --connect-to`, чтобы перенаправить свой запрос

```
curl -H "Authorization:Basic <base64user_pass>" --connect-to accounting.local:443:134.44.100.60 https://accounting.local/api/v1/Accountant/service?toDate=2020-10-01
```

7. И тут все заиграло яркими красками.

Ну, и разобравшись написал скрипт на python с таким поведением.

Осталось понять, насколько все это можно легко перенести в производственную конфигурацию.

Comment: а просто requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, verify=False) не спасал?

Comment: к сожалению, нет. Если не использовать верификацию ответ от сервера был, что данного URL не существует. Если использовать стандартные сертификаты, ответ от сервера, ошибка SSL

Comment: тогда ок, спасибо за ответ!